# How android apps track, if app is previously installed or not?

Tags: android

**Hi, I am new to android development. I don't know any other platform better than Stack overflow, so please forgive me if this is the wrong place to ask this question.**

> I want to know, How android application track, if particular mobile is previously installed it or not?

For example, the recharge application, which is giving some money on first signup.If user uninstall and re-install the app again then the app track the phone and don't signup bonus again.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In that case one have to save the device id and store it to remote database.

```
private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                            Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

But after reseting a device this hardware id is wiped and a new one will come in place of that.

Whenever a user install your app just check at the time of signup if the device id is matching or not.

Hope this will help you.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

for this you have to add too many checks around, but for start you can add some checks like below:

- create a file with specific encrypted content on users disk in some nested folder automatically which you will be sure the user could not find out and relate to your app. on each install check if any such file already exist or not. if exists, the app was previously installed otherwise not.
- One more check, get the mac address of the device, and send in an api to your server and make it store there. On each install when user try to sign up check if this specific mac address already exists or not? if exists then app was previously installed on this one other wise not.
- Get the user IP and network info and send to server to store, if too many requests from the same network info or IP detected, then alarm a scam or black list the IP.
- Add mobile number verification on signup as well. This will minimize the scams by a very large ratio.
- Also you can identify user by its input patterns (Also called signatures). How fast is the user when he/she types. Not just the typing speed also the check the pattern of the speed i.e. how much gap was between two specific characters. and when such patterns match for more and more character your algorithm will pop out. But this is way more complex than it seems. Poor implementation of the algorithm can block some very genuine users, so be careful with this one.

Almost all of these can be bypassed by very professional hackers. So try to make combination of such methods to make it harder for them. and its impossible for normal users. But always assume the worst case scenarios.
You can do some more R&D and can come up with more security checks as well. But these will help you go quite ahead.

Hope it helps----Happy coding.